# How can you display Matplotlib objects in a GUI using qtdesigner?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5, heatmap, pyqtgraph

I have attempted to integrate matplotlib figures into a GUI desined in qt designer and have not been able to get it to correctly integrate the two.

How would I go about promoting/altering/ect a QGraphicsView object into a  canvas that can display a figure generated by matplotlib? [This Example](https://www.swharden.com/wp/2016-07-30-live-data-in-pyqt4-with-matplotlibwidget/) discusses EXACTLY what I'm struggling with but references using a matplotlibwidget, which doesn't exist in my version of Qtdesigner?

I've seen ways of designing the qtapplication window **around** a matplotlib canvas from scratch, but have not been able to take a **qtdesigner built gui** and implement matplotlib, since the objects are integrated in a more complicated manner when using the designer.

Comment: What is your question? In SO you should only ask one question per post, so the button says `ask question`, does not say `ask questions`.

Comment: The question reads very confusingly. First of all, pyqtgraph has nothing to do with matplotlib or seaborn. So you need to decide whether you want to use pyqtgraph or matplotlib/seaborn. Same with QGraphicsView - this is a PyQt object, which cannot be put into a matplotlib figure. If the question is how to integrate a matplotlib canvas into a PyQt window, there are a lot of questions on SO around. You would need to tell exactly what problem you have using any of those examples.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your issue regarding [the example](https://www.swharden.com/wp/2016-07-30-live-data-in-pyqt4-with-matplotlibwidget/) and indeed, when I ran the [corresponding code from GitHub](https://github.com/swharden/Python-GUI-examples/tree/master/2016-07-30_qt_matplotlib_sine_scroll), I got the error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'matplotlibwidget'
```

The issue is that the `MatplotLibWidget` is part of the WinPython distribution and therefore only available out-of-the-box if you use WinPython.

I've found the source code of the `MatplotlibWidget` [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/winpython/pyqtdesignerplugins/ci/default/tree/matplotlibwidget.py#l9). To make the examples work place it in a file called `matplotlibwidget.py` in the same directory as the example code.

**Edit:** I created an issue about it [here](https://github.com/swharden/Python-GUI-examples/issues/7)